# Granting RBAC roles in k8s cluster using terraform

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, rbac

I want to assign `RBAC` rule to a user providing access to all the resources except `'create'` and `'delete'` verb in `'namespace'` resource using Terraform.

Currently we have rule as stated below:

```
rule {
    api_groups = ["*"]
    resources  = ["*"]
    verbs      = ["*"]
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

As we can find in the [Role and ClusterRole documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole), permissions (rules) are purely additive - there are no "deny" rules:

> Role and ClusterRole
> An RBAC Role or ClusterRole contains rules that represent a set of permissions. Permissions are purely additive (there are no "deny" rules).

The list of possible verbs can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/#determine-the-request-verb):
[image]

You need to provide all verbs that should be applied to the resources contained in the rule.
Instead of:

```
verbs      = ["*"]
```

Provide required verbs e.g.:

```
verbs      = ["get", "list", "patch", "update", "watch"]
```

As an example, I've created an `example-role` `Role` and an `example_role_binding` `RoleBinding`.
The `example_role_binding` `RoleBinding` grants the permissions defined in the `example-role` `Role` to user `john`.
**NOTE:** For details on using the following resources, see the [kubernetes_role](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/role) and [kubernetes_role_binding](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/role_binding) resource documentation.

```
resource "kubernetes_role" "example_role" {
  metadata {
    name      = "example-role"
    namespace = "default"
  }

  rule {
    api_groups = ["*"]
    resources  = ["*"]
    verbs      = ["get", "list", "patch", "update", "watch"]
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_role_binding" "example_role_binding" {
  metadata {
    name      = "example_role_binding"
    namespace = "default"
  }
  role_ref {
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
    kind      = "Role"
    name      = "example-role"
  }

  subject {
    kind      = "User"
    name      = "john"
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
  }
}
```

Additionally, I've created the `test_user.sh` Bash script to quickly check if it works as expected:
**NOTE:** You may need to modify the variables `namespace`, `resources`, and `user` to fit your needs.

```
$ cat test_user.sh
#!/bin/bash

namespace=default
resources="pods deployments"
user=john

echo "=== NAMESPACE: ${namespace} ==="
for verb in create delete get list patch update watch; do
    echo "-- ${verb} --"
    for resource in ${resources}; do
        echo -n "${resource}: "
        kubectl auth can-i ${verb} ${resource} -n ${namespace} --as=${user}
    done
done

$ ./test_user.sh
=== NAMESPACE: default ===
-- create --
pods: no
deployments: no
-- delete --
pods: no
deployments: no
-- get --
pods: yes
deployments: yes
-- list --
pods: yes
deployments: yes
...
```