# Scheduled restarts on kubernetes using terraform

Tags: kubernetes, cron, terraform, scheduling, kubernetes-pod

I run a kubernetes cluster on aws managed by terraform. I'd like to automatically restart the pods in the cluster at some regular interval, maybe weekly. Since the entire cluster is managed by terraform, I'd like to run the auto restart command through terraform as well.

At first I assumed that kubernetes would have some kind of ttl for its pods, but that does not seem to be the case.

Elsewhere on SO I've seen the ability to run auto restarts using a cron job managed by kubernetes (eg: [How to schedule pods restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52422300/how-to-schedule-pods-restart)). Terraform has a relevant resource -- the [kubernetes_cron_job](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/cron_job) -- but I can't fully understand how to set it up with the permissions necessary to actually run.

Would appreciate some feedback!

Below is what I've tried:

```
resource "kubernetes_cron_job" "deployment_restart" {
  metadata {
    name = "deployment-restart"
  }
  spec {
    concurrency_policy            = "Forbid"
    schedule                      = "0 8 * * *"
    starting_deadline_seconds     = 10
    successful_jobs_history_limit = 10
    job_template {
      metadata {}
      spec {
        backoff_limit              = 2
                active_deadline_seconds      = 600
        template {
          metadata {}
          spec {
                        service_account_name = var.service_account.name
            container {
              name    = "kubectl"
              image   = "bitnami/kubectl"
              command = ["kubectl rollout restart deploy"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_role" "deployment_restart" {
  metadata {
    name      = "deployment-restart"
  }

  rule {
    api_groups = ["apps", "extensions"]
    resources  = ["deployments"]
    verbs      = ["get", "list", "patch", "watch"]
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_role_binding" "deployment_restart" {
  metadata {
    name      = "deployment-restart"
  }
  role_ref {
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
    kind      = "Role"
    name      = kubernetes_role.deployment_restart.metadata[0].name
  }

  subject {
    kind      = "ServiceAccount"
    name      = var.service_account.name 
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
  }
}
```

This was based on a combination of [Granting RBAC roles in k8s cluster using terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67186483/granting-rbac-roles-in-k8s-cluster-using-terraform) and [How to schedule pods restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52422300/how-to-schedule-pods-restart).

Currently getting the following error:
`Error: RoleBinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "deployment-restart" is invalid: subjects[0].apiGroup: Unsupported value: "rbac.authorization.k8s.io": supported values: ""`

Comment: So, you are getting an error message, when running it? Or what are you missing?

Comment: @FritzDuchardt updated with what I tried and what error I'm getting

Answer (score 0):

As per the official documentation `rolebinding.subjects.apiGroup` for Service Accounts should be empty.

```
kubectl explain rolebinding.subjects.apiGroup
```

> KIND:     RoleBinding VERSION:  rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
>
> FIELD:    apiGroup
>
> DESCRIPTION:
> APIGroup holds the API group of the referenced subject. Defaults to "" for
> ServiceAccount subjects. Defaults to "rbac.authorization.k8s.io" for User
> and Group subjects.